# Configuring GitLab to use SAML OmniAuth with an Active Directory IdP

Tags: git, ldap, gitlab, omniauth, saml

I am in the process of altering an existing `GitLab` installation to use `SAML` rather than `LDAP` for authentication.

At this point, users can successfully sign into the Web application using the 'Sign in with Saml' button. I am unclear, however, about what seems to be a difference between the LDAP and SAML approaches: users with accounts created via an LDAP sign-in can then access Git repositories (e.g. using clone, push, ...) using their LDAP usernames and passwords, but users with accounts created via a SAML sign-in cannot.

Through experimentation, I’ve found that users can access the Git repositories if they use the GitLab UI to set a separate GitLab account password on the account that is created during the initial `SAML` interaction. I was pointed in this direction by a GitLab message that appeared after creating a project under one of the new user accounts: 'You won't be able to pull or push project code via HTTPS until you set a password on your account'.

It seems possible that this separate password configuration is only necessary because I’ve misconfigured the SAML integration somehow. So, my question is whether I am wrong to expect that authenticating access to the GitLab-hosted Git repositories would work the same regardless of whether `SAML` or `LDAP` is used? If not, does anyone know of relevant SAML configuration settings that I should review?

In case it’s of interest: I have posted a similar question to the `GitLab Google` group, but I have not received any responses there yet.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I'm responding anyway in hopes it helps someone else who stumbles upon this question.

An important distinction between LDAP and SAML is that SAML is a web-based single sign on technology. Part of the SAML sign in process happens between the user's client (browser) and the SAML server directly and then GitLab verifies that information on the backend. In contrast, when given a user's LDAP password GitLab can connect directly to the LDAP server and verify the identity.

Many GitLab users utilize a combination of LDAP and SAML. SAML provides seamless single sign-on for the web side while LDAP allows Git over HTTPS to accept passwords and also opens the door to advanced features like LDAP Group Sync in Enterprise Edition.